# Excel get the next month from the selected month in a list?

Tags: excel, monthcalendar

I have a dropdown box with the following listed values:

```
January 
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October 
November
December
```

Let's say a user selects 'January from my list:

I have a cell, let's call it Cell B1 and in it i have this formula

```
=A1
```

This produces 'January' in cell B1.

However in cell C1, i need to be able to +1 to which ever month is shown in Cell B1.

So if A1 = January, then B1 also = January. But C1 needs to equal February for example.

I have tried simply doing this formula in C1:

```
=B1 + 1
```

But because i need my month to be in text rather than number, this won't work and shows #Value error.

Please can someone show me how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(DATEVALUE("01-"&A1&"-"&YEAR(NOW())))+1,1),"mmmm")
```

Comment: amazing, this is spot on! I'll accept when it lets me. thanks

Comment: No worries at all, I'm sure someone will be able to find a quicker solution (and smaller function), but it gets the job done in the mean time

Answer (score 0):

Select Cell B1. In cell format, select custom format and type : **mmmm**

then just drag the corner of this cell (like you would do to extend a formula) over cell C1 and it will display the next month.